# TypeError: elem.value.equals is not a function

Tags: javascript

I get this error

> TypeError: elem.value.equals is not a function

from calling this function

```
function myFunction2() {
    console.log("###! boton " );
    var elem = document.getElementById("SMSMsg");
    console.log("###! elem " + elem.value );
    if (elem.value.equals("")) {
        alert("Debe seleccionar un registro de la grilla");
    }
    if (!elem.value.equals("")) {
        document.SaveConfirm.submit();
    }   
}
```

from this button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="myFunction2()">
      Enviar!
</button>
```

I have another php that works with the equals

Comment: why not use `if - else` instead of `if elem... - if !elem...`

Answer (score 1):

> *I have another php that works with the equals*

This is Javascript though, right? Not PHP? There is no such method that I know of in Javascript.

You probably want this:

```
if (elem.value === "") {
    alert("Debe seleccionar un registro de la grilla");
} else {
    document.SaveConfirm.submit();
}
```

[Javascript Comparison Operators on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)